# Eclipse: Create key shortcut for command/action programatically

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I know that it is possible to register a key shortcut for commands using the extension point org.eclipse.ui.bindings. An example from [Eclipse FAQs](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_provide_a_keyboard_shortcut_for_my_action%3F):

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
    <key sequence="Ctrl+7"
        commandId="uk.co.example.actions.togglecomment"
        schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
        contextId="uk.co.example.ampleEditorScope"/>
</extension>
```

However, is it possible to do the same thing dynamically at runtime?

Comment: `org.eclipse.ui.keys.IBindingService` is the main interface to the key binding code but it does not seem to have anything to add bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the floowing topic should be related:
http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t44367.html